# How to query sharepoint search api where column value contains space

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I am trying to run a SharePoint api query to match against a column with a specific value.

The column value contains a space which is resulting in the query not working as expected. Returning anything with 'value' in the column rather than just items where the column = 'value 2'.

My current url looks like where $listId is a list guid
     `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(customColumn:value 2)+AND+(ListID:$listId)'&selectproperties='Name,Title,Description,Author,LastModifiedTime,Path'`

What is the syntax for

`(customColumn:value 2)`

That allows me to only return results where customColumn = "value 2"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the endpoint as

```
_api/search/query?querytext='customColumn:value%202'
```

My test Sample:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='Title:Developer%20-%20Wiki1 Author:Lee'
```